# Silverlight Applications to Access SharePoint 2010 Data is not loading

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint

I am trying to load Silverlight DataGrid Control in my SharePoint 2010, I have followed this code example linl. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728647.aspx#Y1200.

I have just replaced this codelines(in MainPage() method):

List Projects = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Calendar");

string camlQueryXml ="asd"+ ""+ "";

Output Error:Could not download the Silverlight application or the Silverlight Plugin did not load.

Comment: string camlQueryXml ="<View><Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><Value Type=\"Counter\">asd</Value></Neq></Where></Query><ViewFields>"+ "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />"+ "</ViewFields></View>";

Answer (score 0):

Check this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265156(v=vs.95).aspx

The silverlight version selected while creating the application should match with the version of plugin installed.